# Calculate curve consisting of clothoids (euler curve) and radiuses

Tags: python, math, curve, radius

I am trying to calculate points for curve, that is required for testing purposes (get a [xy] coordinates in cartesian system).

The desired curve looks like this:

[image: Curve]

I am able to calculate the first clothoid (using python), but can not get the other curves together.

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Thank you.